# How I can pass the data between two controllers?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

First controller is this DataFormController

```
class DataFormController extends \App\Http\Controllers\Controller
{
    public function getDataForm(Request $request) {
      $model = $request->model;
      $uuid = $request->uuid;
       //some codes
             return response()->json(['status' => 'success',
       'settings' => $settings, 'form' => $form, 
       'relations' => $relations, 'values' => $values, 
       'dates' => $dates, 'actions' => $actions, 
       'translations' => $translations, 'count' => $count, 
       'max' => $limitationMax, 'limitReached' => $limitReached,
      ], 
        200);
}
```

I want to pass  data values from DataFormController  to another controller PointController

```
class PointController extends Controller {

  public function newTransaction(Request $request){
   //Some codes
}
}
```

How can i solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

```
use App\Http\Controllers\PointController;

class DataFormController extends Controller
{
    public function getDataForm(Request $request) {
      $model = $request->model;
      $uuid = $request->uuid;
       //some codes
      $response = ['status' => 'success',
                'settings' => $settings, 'form' => $form, 
                'relations' => $relations, 'values' => $values, 
                'dates' => $dates, 'actions' => $actions, 
                'translations' => $translations, 'count' => $count, 
                'max' => $limitationMax, 'limitReached' => $limitReached];

        $transactionReq = new Request($response);
        
        /**
         * if you declared the newTransaction as static you
         * can call that function as below 
         */
        PointController::newTransactionStatic($transactionReq);

        /**
         * If the function is not static
         */
        $pointController = new PointController();
        $pointController->newTransactionNonStatic($transactionReq);



        return response()->json($response,200);
}
```

You can declare the functions as static or non static as you desire, if you want to get the request in pointcontroller :

```
class PointController extends Controller {

    /**
     * NON STATIC FUNCTION
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return void
     */
    public function newTransactionNonStatic(Request $request){
    //Some codes
    }

    /**
     * STATIC FUNCTION
     *
     * @param array $request
     * @return void
     */
    public static function newTransactionStatic(Request $request){
    //Some codes
    }
}
```

If you want to get the "dates","count","values" from DataFormController :

```
         $pointsData = \Arr::only($response,['dates','count','values']);
        /**
         * if you declared the newTransaction as static you
         * can call that function as below 
         */
        PointController::newTransactionStatic($pointsData);

        /**
         * If the function is not static
         */
        $pointController = new PointController();
        $pointController->newTransactionNonStatic($pointsData);
```

Since we are passing the values as array change it accordingly in the point controller

```
 class PointController extends Controller {

    /**
     * NON STATIC FUNCTION
     *
     * @param array $request
     * @return void
     */
    public function newTransactionNonStatic(array $request){
       $dates = $request['dates'];
       $count = $request['count'];
       $values = $request['values'];
       /**
        * Or for easier way call the extract php function
        * eg : extract($request);
        * then easily use the array keys as variables  
        *  -> $dates, $count, $values etc.
        */

    }

    /**
     * STATIC FUNCTION
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return void
     */
    public static function newTransactionStatic(array $request){
       $dates = $request['dates'];
       $count = $request['count'];
       $values = $request['values'];
       /**
        * Or for easier way call the extract php function
        * eg : extract($request);
        * then easily use the array keys as variables  
        *  -> $dates, $count, $values etc.
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: In PointController I want to get the value of "dates","count","values" which are in DataFormController @jeybin George

Comment: @ArvindSHa kindly change the values that are passing through the function according to your needs

Comment: @ArvindSHa checkout the edited answer