# How can i pass the data between two controllers?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

Here ids my first controller "DataFormController"

```
class DataFormController extends \App\Http\Controllers\Controller
 {
public function getDataForm(Request $request) {
       $model = $request->model;
      $uuid = $request->uuid;
     //some codes
return response()->json(['status' => 'success',
      'settings' => $settings, 'form' => $form, 
       'relations' => $relations, 'values' => $values, 
      'dates' => $dates, 'actions' => $actions, 
      'translations' => $translations, 'count' => $count, 
       'max' => $limitationMax, 'limitReached' => $limitReached,

200);
}
```

Routes for "DataFormController"

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'app', 'middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
Route::get('data-form', '\Platform\Controllers\App\DataFormController@getDataForm');
})
```

I want to pass data "values","dates","count" from DataFormController to another controller "PointController"

```
class PointController extends Controller {

  public function newTransaction(Request $request){
   //Some codes
     return response()->json([
     'status'=>'success',
     'mgs'=>$data
],200);
}
}
```

Routes for "PointController"

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'campaign', 'middleware' => 'auth:customer'], function() {
    Route::post('newTransaction', '\Platform\Controllers\Campaign\PointController@newTransaction');
})
```

How can i solve this problem?

In PointController I want to get the value of "dates","count","values" which are in DataFormController

Comment: You could make a separate class and put the codes in `newTransaction` in there and then call that from both `getDataForm` and `newTransaction`. That's typically how you'd reuse the same code in OOP

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How I can pass the data between two controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75045874/how-i-can-pass-the-data-between-two-controllers)

Answer (score 1):

```
use App\Http\Controllers\PointController;

class DataFormController extends Controller
{
    public function getDataForm(Request $request) {
      $model = $request->model;
      $uuid = $request->uuid;
       //some codes
      $response = ['status' => 'success',
                'settings' => $settings, 'form' => $form, 
                'relations' => $relations, 'values' => $values, 
                'dates' => $dates, 'actions' => $actions, 
                'translations' => $translations, 'count' => $count, 
                'max' => $limitationMax, 'limitReached' => $limitReached];

        $transactionReq = new Request($response);
        
        /**
         * if you declared the newTransaction as static you
         * can call that function as below 
         */
        PointController::newTransactionStatic($transactionReq);

        /**
         * If the function is not static
         */
        $pointController = new PointController();
        $pointController->newTransactionNonStatic($transactionReq);



        return response()->json($response,200);
}
```

You can declare the functions as static or non static as you desire, if you want to get the request in pointcontroller :

```
class PointController extends Controller {

    /**
     * NON STATIC FUNCTION
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return void
     */
    public function newTransactionNonStatic(Request $request){
    //Some codes
    }

    /**
     * STATIC FUNCTION
     *
     * @param array $request
     * @return void
     */
    public static function newTransactionStatic(Request $request){
    //Some codes
    }
}
```

If you want to get the "dates","count","values" from DataFormController :

```
         $pointsData = \Arr::only($response,['dates','count','values']);
        /**
         * if you declared the newTransaction as static you
         * can call that function as below 
         */
        PointController::newTransactionStatic($pointsData);

        /**
         * If the function is not static
         */
        $pointController = new PointController();
        $pointController->newTransactionNonStatic($pointsData);
```

Since we are passing the values as array change it accordingly in the point controller

```
 class PointController extends Controller {

    /**
     * NON STATIC FUNCTION
     *
     * @param array $request
     * @return void
     */
    public function newTransactionNonStatic(array $request){
       $dates = $request['dates'];
       $count = $request['count'];
       $values = $request['values'];
       /**
        * Or for easier way call the extract php function
        * eg : extract($request);
        * then easily use the array keys as variables  
        *  -> $dates, $count, $values etc.
        */

    }

    /**
     * STATIC FUNCTION
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return void
     */
    public static function newTransactionStatic(array $request){
       $dates = $request['dates'];
       $count = $request['count'];
       $values = $request['values'];
       /**
        * Or for easier way call the extract php function
        * eg : extract($request);
        * then easily use the array keys as variables  
        *  -> $dates, $count, $values etc.
        */
    }
}
```